# jQuery - Is it possible to set value in a hidden textbox using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to set a value in a hidden textbox using the jquery.

I have multiple forms that are same but need to change one field, so i want to use the field dynamically.

What i have tried. [fiddle_link](https://jsfiddle.net/frayne_konok/txpmd7br/1/)

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li class="hidden"><input class='hidden_val' type='text' value=''/></li>
  <li><input type='text' value='2'/></li>
  <li><input type='text' value='3'/></li>
  <li><input type='text' value='4'/></li>
  <li><input type='text' value='5'/></li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function(){
    $(".hidden_val").val(1);
});
```

**Css:**

```
.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: use css visibility: hidden; option

Comment: @pTi if you downvote me then please give the solution also.

Comment: sorry I dint down voted

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question ask by me a lot of time ago, and now a days i got downvote here, I don't know why, so please close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question: Yes, this is possible.

But why don't you use: **type="hidden"** instead: **display: none** ?

Comment: my question is not about to hidden a textbox. Just set the value in it using jQuery. If you can then please do it for me, i have a fiddle link in my question.

Answer (score 1):

why u don't use hidden fields?

```
<input type="hidden" value="your value" />
```

all you need is to change your input type attribute to "hidden"

Comment: my question is not about to hidden a textbox. Just set the value in it using jQuery. If you can then please do it for me, i have a fiddle link in my question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a hidden input field just use

```
<input type='hidden' value=''/>
```

and you can place that input field anywhere in your html. You don't have to put it in the

```
<li></li>
```

That way you can change the value and be sure that it won't be shown.

Comment: my question is not about to hidden a textbox. Just set the value in it using jQuery. If you can then please do it for me, i have a fiddle link in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="texens" name="user" value="" />
<button>Set Value</button>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#texens").val("Hurray");
    alert($("#texens").val());
  });
});
```

Comment: my question is not about to hidden a textbox. Just set the value in it using jQuery. If you can then please do it for me, i have a fiddle link in my question.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your question right, try

```
$(function() {
    modval(6);
});

function modval(valu){
    $(".hidden_val").val(valu);
    alert($(".hidden_val").val());
}
```

and just pass the number you want to use as the argument when you call modval.
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2m87jtLo/)

Answer (score 0):

`$(".hidden_val").val(1);` is setting the value to 1.
Am i missing the point of the question?